# Is there a Numeric Format String for the following?

Tags: c#, number-formatting

I'm using C# and I have many integers.

I was wondering if there was a numeric format string that would display the following:

```
12
```

as

```
+12
```

This is needed as the application I'm working with is mathematical, and when attempting to display something like x + y when x = 2 and y can be either -2 or say for instance 3. I don't want to be displaying:

```
2 + -2 and 2 + 3
```

if you understand what I am getting at.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there's a *standard* format string that does that, but you could use:

```
x.ToString("+#;-#;+0")
```

That will give "+1234", "-1234" and "+0" for values 1234, -1234 and 0 respectively. I *think* that's what you wanted.

Comment: Works like a dream. Thanks a lot Jon, I knew there'd be an easier way!

Answer (score 0):

You can display 12 as +12 with the following formatting:

```
string.Format("{0:+0;-0}", 12);
```